# How to use the element from XML (SAXParser) and show it to table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, saxparser

I'm working on a web application that using Spring MVC and Hibernate,

I've field that the type is Clob and the value is XML, 
The clob was parse using SAXParser before,
How to use the element from SAXParser and show it to table,

[image: Output from SAXParser]

I Really have no idea to show the element from SAXParser to my table (JSP)

[image: table]

this is my code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/Detail-BPJS-TK.html")
public ModelAndView listDetailBPJSTK(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, Exception{
    if(!((request.getParameter("MESSAGEID")) == null)){
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
        //140721438362
        //DetailBPJS detailbpjs = detailbpjsService.get(MESSAGEID);

        //String tes = detailbpjs.getMESSAGEID();
        //System.out.println(tes);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernatesoaappbpjstk.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        String pay = "PAYMENT";
        String sub = "PROCESSED";

        Query query = session.createQuery("from DetailBPJS where TRANSACTION = :tra and SUBTRANSACTION = :sub and MESSAGEID = :mes");
        query.setParameter("tra", pay);
        query.setParameter("sub", sub);
        query.setParameter("mes", MESSAGEID);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List <DetailBPJS> result = query.list();

        if(result.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Please, check the 'No. Billing' again!!");
            System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
            model.addAttribute("errorMessageBPJSTK", "true");
        }else{
            DetailBPJS data = (DetailBPJS)result.get(0);
            String nom1 = data.getTRANSACTION();
            String nom2 = data.getSUBTRANSACTION();
            String nom3 = data.getUUID();
            Clob nom4 = data.getRAWDATA();

            System.out.println(nom1 + " - " + nom2 + " - " + nom3 + " - " + nom4);
            //140721438362

            //convert clob to java.io.reader
            Reader myclob = nom4.getCharacterStream();
            System.out.println(myclob);

            //create InputSource from Reader
            InputSource myinput = new InputSource(myclob);
            System.out.println(myinput);

            try {

                SAXParserFactory factoryz = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxParser = factoryz.newSAXParser();
                System.out.println(saxParser);

                DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler(){
                    boolean b_num   = false;
                    boolean b_krb   = false;
                    boolean b_reqid = false;
                    boolean b_ch    = false;
                    boolean b_kb    = false;
                    boolean b_tgl   = false;
                    boolean tot     = false;
                    boolean jht     = false;
                    boolean jkk     = false;
                    boolean jkm     = false;

                    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("messageId")){
                            b_num = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:kodeRefBank")){
                            b_krb = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:reqId")){
                            b_reqid = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:chId")){
                            b_ch = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:kodeBank")){
                            b_kb = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("bpjs:tglTrx")){
                            b_tgl = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("totalAmount")){
                            tot = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJHT")){
                            jht = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJKK")){
                            jkk = true;
                        }
                        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("amountJKM")){
                            jkm = true;
                        }
                    }

                    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException{
                        if (b_num){
                            System.out.println("(1) Value of Billing Number : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            String tust = new String(ch, start, length);
                            System.out.println(tust);
                            b_num = false;
                        }
                        if (b_krb){
                            System.out.println("(2) Value Of KodeRefBank : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_krb = false;
                        }
                        if (b_reqid){
                            System.out.println("(3) Value Of ReqId : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_reqid = false;
                        }
                        if (b_ch){
                            System.out.println("(4) Value Of ChId : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_ch = false;
                        }
                        if (b_kb){
                            System.out.println("(5) Value Of KodeBank : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_kb = false;
                        }
                        if (b_tgl){
                            System.out.println("(6) Value Of TglTrx : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            b_tgl = false;
                        }
                        if (tot){
                            System.out.println("(7) Value Of Tot : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            tot = false;
                        }
                        if (jht){
                            System.out.println("(8) Value Of JHT : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jht = false;
                        }
                        if (jkk){
                            System.out.println("(9) Value Of JKK : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jkk = false;
                        }
                        if (jkm){
                            System.out.println("(10) Value Of JKM : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                            jkm = false;
                        }
                    }
                };
                saxParser.parse(myinput, handler);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            //SAX Parser to parse this xml

        }
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please, check the 'No. Billing' again!!");
        String MESSAGEID = request.getParameter("MESSAGEID");
        System.out.println(MESSAGEID);
        model.addAttribute("errorMessageBPJSTK", "true");
    }

    return listDetailBPJS(model);
}
```

any help will be pleasure :) ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly add the `String` values to `ModelMap` and access them from the jsp same as "`errorMessageBPJSTK`".

```
if(b_num){
    model.addAttribute("billingNumber",new String(ch, start, length));   
    b_num = false;
}
if(b_krb){
    model.addAttribute("kodeRefBank",new String(ch, start, length));
    b_krb = false;
}
```

and in jsp access them like;

```
<td>Billing Number : </td>
<td>${billingNumber}</td>
```